# Issue with TikZ \tkzFct: No Color for C_{\exp} and C_{\ln} ​

Tags: tkz-fct

I'm currently working on a LaTeX document where I use TikZ along with the `tkz-fct` package to draw mathematical functions. However, I'm facing an issue where I'm unable to assign colors to the curves `\mathcal{C}_{f}` and `\mathcal{C}_{g}`.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4]
    \tkzAxeX \tkzAxeY
 \tkzFct[domain=-4:4,samples=800,draw=blue,thick]{exp(x)}
  \tkzText(2,4){($\mathcal{C}_{\exp}$)}
 \tkzFct[domain=0.01:4,samples=800,draw=red,thick]{log(x)}
    \tkzText(4,2){($\mathcal{C}_{\ln}$)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that the color settings for `\mathcal{C}_{f}` and `\mathcal{C}_{g}` are not taking effect, and both curves appear in default colors.

Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how can I correctly assign colors to these curves?

Comment: Sorry, can't compile your code ...

Comment: @MS-SPO Please, check now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See example in *ch 5.1 Ajouter un label* in the [manual](https://de.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-fct/doc/tkz-fct.pdf). Text color seems to be assigned as `color=<color>` .

The labels are colored:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4]
    \tkzAxeX \tkzAxeY
 \tkzFct[domain=-4:4,samples=800,draw=blue,color=brown,thick]{exp(x)}
  \tkzText(2,4){($\mathcal{C}_{\exp}$)}
 \tkzFct[domain=0.01:4,samples=800,draw=red,color=red,thick]{log(x)}
    \tkzText(4,2){($\mathcal{C}_{\ln}$)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

BTW, probably because it's built on Tikz, setting an option with `\tkzText` seems to work, too:

```
 \tkzFct[domain=0.01:4,samples=800,draw=red,thick]{log(x)}
    \tkzText[teal](4,2){($\mathcal{C}_{\ln}$)}
```

[image]

For reference, relating to [Alain's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707616/issue-with-tikz-tkzfct-no-color-for-c-exp-and-c-ln/707626?noredirect=1#comment1759330_707626), these are the .gnuplot files Texmaker/pdflatex created:

```
set table "tkzFctGrid.tkzfonct.table"; set format "%.5f"
set samples 200.0; plot [x=-5.000000000000000000:5.000000000000000000] (((-x**2-2*x+3))-0)/1
```

```
set table "tkz-fct-colors.tkzfonct.table"; set format "%.5f"
set samples 800.0; plot [x=0.010000000000000000:4.000000000000000000] ((log(x))-0)/1
```

Comment: please, give me the whole code ?

Comment: It‘s there. Just move to 3rd line from the end and put an option  of your choice.

Comment: "I'm experiencing an issue where the curves are missing in my LaTeX document. I am using Windows 10 with TeXstudio as my LaTeX editor. I had previously used Overleaf without any problems before attempting to compile the document on my PC."

Comment: Do you have gnuplot installed? I haven't, so the curves are missing, and there was a hint during compile. Is that your remark?

Comment: @Educ If the curves are not displayed, there are several possible causes. The first is that gnuplot is not installed. The second is that gnuplot is installed but not found. Finally, you need to authorize the system to launch an external program using the `option --shell-escape` option. All this can be found on the WEB and is specific to the system, editor, etc.

Comment: @Educ To point you in the right direction, you need to check the files produced. If your file is named `test`, then if everything's working properly you'll get a `test.tkzfonct.gnuplot` file and a `test.tkzfonct.table` file. The first is the command sent by TikZ to gnuplot (function, domain, number of points). The second, if gnuplot is found, is the table created by gnuplot and sent to TikZ(fct). If the files are missing, open `test.log` and there should be ` \write18 enabled.` in the first few lines. Type `gnuplot` in the search box! There are lots of answers.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Thank you I solved the issue see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707629/missing-curves-in-latex-document-and-gnuplot-installation-issue/707642#707642

Comment: @MS-SPO I took the liberty of editing in order to add the curves.

Comment: @egreg, thanks: great improvement :)