# Missing Curves in LaTeX Document and Gnuplot Installation Issue

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, tkz-fct

I'm encountering an issue with my LaTeX document where the curves are missing when using TeXstudio on Windows 10. Notably, I had no problems when working on Overleaf. Additionally, I attempted to install Gnuplot on my Windows 10 system.

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4]
    \tkzAxeX \tkzAxeY
    \tkzFct[domain=-4:4,samples=800,draw=blue,thick]{exp(x)}
    \tkzText[text=blue](2,4){($\mathcal{C}_{\exp}$)}
    \tkzFct[domain=0.01:4,samples=800,draw=red,thick]{log(x)}
    \tkzText[text=red](4,2){($\mathcal{C}_{\ln}$)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example works fine for me if I remove the `center` environment. Can you show your .log file so we can see if you compile with shell-escape enabled?

Comment: @thank you I solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

To resolve the issue of curves not being displayed in the PDF produced in Windows 10 using TeXstudio version 4.7.2 (git 4.7.2), follow these steps:

Configure TeXstudio:

Open TeXstudio and navigate to the "Configure TeXstudio" menu.
Go to the "Build" tab and select "User Commands."
In the "User Commands" section, add the following command:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape %.tex
```

[image]

Install Gnuplot:

Ensure that Gnuplot is installed on your system.
During the installation process, make sure to check the option that says "Add application directory to your PATH environment variable." This is crucial for TeXstudio to locate Gnuplot.

[image]

Configure TeXstudio Editor:

Open the TeXstudio editor.
Select the "Tools" menu and then choose "User (Gnuplot)."

[image]

By following these steps, you ensure that TeXstudio is configured to use the appropriate build command, Gnuplot is installed with the necessary settings, and the TeXstudio editor is set up to recognize Gnuplot.

These adjustments should address the problem, and you should now be able to generate PDFs with properly displayed curves in your Windows 10 environment using TeXstudio.

[image]